# Creating a Dynamic Google Earth Web Link

Tags: google-earth

I've been tasked with creating a Google Earth Web link programmatically when given coordinates. I have the street address as well, where I'd ideally like to drop a pin.

For example, I can get a link to the white house using its lat/lon at a distance of 150 meters like this:

https://earth.google.com/web/@38.8976633,-77.0365739,150d

If I search using the google earth web app I can generate a link with a pin, where a few of the parameters in the link change slightly:

https://earth.google.com/web/@38.8976763,-77.0365298,18.0497095a,800.41606338d,35y,0h,45t,0r/data=ChIaEAoIL20vMDgxc3EYAiABKAIoAg

Am I able to dynamically generate the `data` element, or whichever element creates the pin, at my desired location? I've also had trouble finding the correct distance `d` and elevation `a` parameters in my links.

Answer (score 4):

As you found, you can generate links to specific views in the Google Earth web client by adding the correct parameters to the URL, including the latitude, longitude and altitude (a) of the view target, and the distance (d) of the camera from that target.  Note that altitude and distance are both in meters, and altitude is above sea level, not above ground elevation. If you look at the a and d parameters that Earth puts in the URL as you fly around, often altitude will be the terrain (or builing-top) elevation at the target lat/lon, and the distance will be how far the camera is from that altitude. The other available parameters include heading (h) and roll (r).

So long as your tilt (t) remains zero, then altitude and distance should be interchangeable, or if both are >0, then they will be summed together for the final camera height above sea level.  But if you add a tilt (zero degrees is looking straight down), then the altitude determines the elevation of the view target (above the lat & lon location), and the distance determines how far the camera is from that point.  If you make d=0, then altitude will define both the view target and camera height above sea level. If you make a=0, then the distance will be from the lat,lon at sea level (even if that's underground).

[image: Google Earth basic view parameters diagram]

Unfortunately there's no way to manually construct the data parameter, as it can contain many different things.  To do that right would require an API, which Earth for Web currently does not provide. Hopefully that kind of functionality will come after Earth finishes its work to become cross-browser compatible via Web Assembly. Until then, there's not a way to add a point the map via just a URL.

Comment: This seems to confirm some of my initial suspicions about altitude and distance. Any recommendation on programmatically obtaining elevation above sea level from a lat/lon or address? I think that would help in this situation to set a reasonable camera distance.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately there's not currently a way to specify an altitude relative to the terrain in the URL. One way you could do this is to have a script look up the terrain altitude at your lat/lon using an Elevation API, or from some other dataset, and then use that to construct your URL.